# question on continuous

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a, b]$, where $a < b$, such that $f(x)\neq0$ for all $x\in [a, b]$.

Prove that there is $c>0$, such that either $f(x)>c$ for all $x\in [a, b]$ or $f(x)<-c$ for all $x\in [a, b]$

Comment: Intermediate  value theorem states that if f(x) ne 0 on [a,b] then f (x) is always positive or negative on [a,b].    Prove f (x) is bounded for [a,b].  Let c be sup/inf f ([a,b]).

Answer (score 1):

This is a harder argument. If you want a simpler one, do look in the edit.

Suppose the continuous function $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Then, by compactness of $[a,b]$, $f$ attains a maximum $M$ and minimum $m$ on $[a,b]$. Because $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$, it follows that the maximum and the minimum have the same sign (otherwise, the intermediate value theorem gives a contradiction). Let $c = \min \{|M|,|m|\}$. Then, $f(x) > c$ if $f(x)$ is always positive, and $f(x) < -c$ if $f(x)$ is always negative.

---

Edit: This is a simpler argument.

First of all, note that $f(x)$ is either positive on $[a,b]$ or negative on $[a,b]$. To see this, note that if $f(x) > 0$ and $f(y)<0$, then by the intermediate value property there exists $z$ between $x$ and $y$ such that $f(z)=0$, which contradicts our assumption that $f$ does not attain zero on $[a,b]$.

Hence, WLOG assume $f$ is positive on $[a,b]$. We will show that there is some $m>0$ such that $f(x) > m$ on $[a,b]$.

Suppose the above is not true i.e. for all $m>0$, there is an $a$ such that $f(a) < m$. Take $m$ to be a term of a sequence decreasing to zero, like $\frac{1}{n}$. Then, there exist $a_n \in [a,b]$ such that $f(a_n) < \frac{1}{n}$. Consider the sequence $\{a_n\}$.

This sequence, being in $[a,b]$, is bounded, hence there exists a convergent subsequence $\{ a_{n_k}\} \to d$. However, because $[a,b]$ is closed, $d \in [a,b]$.

By continuity of $f$, since $a_{n_k} \to d$, $f(a_{n_k}) \to f(d)$, but $0 < f(a_{n_k}) < \frac{1}{n}$, so by the squeeze theorem, $f(d) = 0$, which gives a contradiction as $f$ is positive on $[a,b]$.

Hence there is some $m > 0$ such that $f(x)>m$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

A similar argument follows if $f$ is a negative function.

Comment: Based on the question, I am not sure you can use "the image of a compact by a continuous function is a compact". Just a feeling that you need to use simpler arguments

Comment: @Vincent Good point. I think I just assumed it. Maybe I should edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If no such $c$ exists then a sequence $(x_n)$ in $[a,b]$ with $f(x_n)\to 0$ exists. E.g. for every $n$ you can choose $x_n\in[a,b]$ such that $|f(x_n)|<\frac1{n}$.

As any sequence in compact set $[a,b]$ this sequence has a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})$.

If $x\in[a,b]$ denotes its limit then by continuity $f(x)=\lim_{k\to\infty}f(x_{n_k})=0$.

So a contradiction is found.